# Losing connection to MySQL after a while, and not reconnecting

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I'm developing a standalone server which uses JPA+Hibernate to access a MySQL database.

When I start the server, everything is working fine. However, after a while (usually the next morning, if I start it in the afternoon) it will stop working because apparently the connection to MySQL was closed (I see lots of `SocketException`s in the logs). This is probably caused by idling, the server is in development and nobody uses it at night.

I thought Hibernate, JDBC or some other layer below my app would manage the connection and reopen it if neccessary, but apparently not. Is there a configuration parameter I missed?

**`persistence.xml`**

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

```
<persistence-unit name="manager">

<class>example.data.entities.User</class>
<class>example.data.entities.Player</class>

<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="example.data.HibernateDialect" />
    <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3" />
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />

</properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

**`EntityManagerFactory` creation**

```
    log.info("Connecting to database @ " + dbUrl + " using " + dbUser + "/" + dbPass);

    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("manager", Maps.create(
            "javax.persistence.jdbc.user", dbUser,
            "javax.persistence.jdbc.password", dbPass,
            "javax.persistence.jdbc.url", dbUrl
    ));
```

**A query**

```
            try
            {

                TypedQuery<User> q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.email = :mail", User.class);
                q.setParameter("mail", email);
                try {
                    u = q.getSingleResult();
                    log.info("Authenticating: " + u);
                } catch (NoResultException e) {
                    return false;
                }

            } finally {
                em.close();
            }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you suggest, it is because mysql closes idle connections after each `wait_timeout` passes; you have some options to work-around your problem:

- use a connection pool manager, like [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html) or [apache DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/). This will take care of revalidation of connections on request, eventually you can specify which query to run to test if connection is alive.
- set `wait_timeout` in mysql large enough for your use case (default is 8 hrs).
- setup a scheduled task (for instance using [quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)) that refreshes connections, "pinging" the mysql server.

Comment: I'm using c3p0 now. What I don't understand is the benefit of having multiple connections, in  a pool, but it's part of the package so now I have it :p. What good does it do me?

Comment: @Bart van Heukelom: it's a different contract of using db connections, where you can assume a connection is ready when you open it, and that reduces the overhead of closing a connection (which, with a pool, is nothing more that signaling the pool manager that you stopped using the connection). Remember to close each jdbc object as soon as you dont need it when using a pool manager.

Answer (score 4):

mysql driver supports autoReconnect 
the jdbc url will look like
jdbc:mysql://localhost/bms_company?autoReconnect=true

if u suspect mysql is dropping connections 
Try adding the following entries at the end of MySQL's my.ini file. This file 
is located in the MySQL installation's root folder.

#The number of seconds the mysqld server is waiting for a connect packet 
before responding with 'Bad handshake' 
connect_timeout=0

#The number of seconds the server waits for activity on an interactive 
connection before closing it. 
interactive_timeout=2000000

#The number of seconds the server waits for activity on a connection before 
closing it 
wait_timeout=2000000

--Kiran.Kumar

Comment: The first one sounds good but did not work for me. Setting the timeout to such a big value raises other problems: if the application crashes (tomcat in my case) connections will remain alive for a few days and this might raise 'too many connections' error from mysql.