# MYSQL connection lost on Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans

I'm doing some homework and I need to conncect **mysql** with **netbeans** in order to save some certian data. 
I'm losing connection and I dont know why and where.

Here is my code :

```
  public void runThread(int  taban , int tavan) {
    int primNum=0;
       try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("MySQL JDBC Driver not found !!");
        return;
    }



   try{
       Connection con  = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/primenumbers" , "root" , "password123");
       System.out.println("SQL Connection to database established!");
       Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
       int i=taban;

       while(i<tavan){

        boolean tf = TredAsal.isPrime(i);
        if(tf==true) {
        primNum++;

        if(i>15){ 
        String insert = "INSERT INTO primenumbers VALUES (" + i + ")";
        stmt.execute(insert);
        stmt.cancel();
        }
        Thread.sleep(500);
                       }
       i+=2;
       }                          
       con.close();
   }

   catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console1");
   }
  }
```

And code where I'm calling runThread :

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("");
    sb.append(clicks);
    String strI = sb.toString();
    jTextField1.setText(strI);
    int tavan;
    tavan=(int) sqrt(clicks);
    int tredsayisi=0;
    int Brojgrupe;


            TredAsal ta= new TredAsal();
            int x = ta.run(tavan);
            sb2.append("");
            sb2.append(x);
            String strP=sb2.toString();

            if(x<100){

            tredsayisi = 2 ; 
            }
            else {
            tredsayisi=(int) (x/100)+1;
            }
            Brojgrupe = tavan / tredsayisi;
            if(tredsayisi==2 ){
                StringBuilder sb3 = new StringBuilder();
                StringBuilder sb4 = new StringBuilder();
                sb3.append("");
                sb3.append(Brojgrupe);
                sb4.append("");
                sb4.append(tavan);
                String strBit2 = sb3.toString();
                String strBit3 = sb4.toString(); // pravim text za bas i bitis noktasi
                   TredAsal t1 = new TredAsal();
                   TredAsal t2 = new TredAsal();
                   t1.runThread(3, Brojgrupe); //Thread.sleep(1000);
                   t2.runLastThread(tavan, Brojgrupe);// Thread.sleep(1000);
                   jTextField2.setText("2");
                   jTextField9.setText(strBit2);
                   jTextField3.setText(strBit2);
                   jTextField10.setText(strBit3);


     }
```

Every time when I call this function SQL connection is established but at some point is interrupting by something that I can't see.

Comment: no need to create connection inside the for loop. You can create single connection then insert inside the loop.

Comment: paste exact screen shot or error message ( if you get any )

Comment: As said by Damith, connection and statement creation needs to be taken out of loop and when finished, you need to properly close these too.

Comment: I done like that also and again its losing connection. :S DamithGanegoda Sabir_Khan 

There is no error

Comment: I'm just getting message that I wrote in catch "Connection Failed! Check output console"

Comment: I closed with "con.close()" , but the connection is losing again. Don't know what to do :S

Comment: show your updated code ( I guess by editing your question ) and for your case , it looks that PreparedStatement  is better suited. Also show calling code of runThread().

Comment: Edited. 
By the way he is inserting to DB's table few data and after that is losing connection.

Comment: See if kiran.kumar M's answer in this question helps - [Losing connection to MySQL after a while, and not reconnecting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060106/losing-connection-to-mysql-after-a-while-and-not-reconnecting)

Comment: It's with js as i see ..