# Why lose mysql connection after several hours when i configured Django and Nginx in server?

Tags: python, mysql, django, linux

after i configured my Django in Nginx of linux server , i can normally browse my web and connect mysql , but after a while(maybe several hours) ,disaster comes, web shows such infos:

> 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'localhost:3306', system error: 32 Broken pipe
>   `

Here is complete errors:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://labtine.com/logs/2.html
Django Version: 2.0
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'localhost:3306', system error: 32 Broken pipe
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/network.py in send_plain, line 143
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
Python Version: 3.7.6
Python Path:    
['.',
 '',
 '/usr/lib/python37.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
 '/home/cg_log/CG_log/firstApp']
```

Here is the explicit error:

```
......
usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/network.py in send_plain
                self.sock.sendall(packet) 
......
```

i really don't know why  , this problem has puzzled me for a long time , hugely hammered my road to devote to human being .

from now on , i have searched for quite a lot in google , but nothing ends well,is it the cause of concurrency of Mysql?or any other issues?i have looked at my error logs but there was nothing indicate such error...

Comment: Can you look at this question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5060450/7320045

Comment: Do the python bindings to mysql you're using provide an interface to [mysql_ping()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-ping.html)?

Answer (score 0):

It is so wired that such question doesn't have reliable answer or indication in google ,well thanks to the commenters above , i have figured it out now

The cause of this problem is that i created a Mysql connection in front of codes , and it will be invalid after default timeout 8 hours , so this is why emerges such error

Just to set `wait_timeout` in your Linux server to maximum solved the problem

Explicit practice is here :

https://askubuntu.com/a/892859